# Is it ok to say “mutually practice together”?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

Is it correct to say

> This way we can mutually practice together.

Since *mutually* has already been mentioned, is it correct if I use the word *together* at the end? It may be redundant, but is it wrong?

Comment: I'd just drop the *mutually*, it doesn't seem like the right word there. What did you intend it to mean?

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU.

Comment: @tchrist: Any chance you can tell me what I'm missing (a font?) which causes me to only see a dozen "square" symbols in between your ***use*** and ***or*** there? If it makes any difference, I'm running Google Chrome under Vista.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That would be http://i.stack.imgur.com/YgDYJ.png I believe.

Comment: @tchrist: Which I guess means [this is relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654259/), but there are no upvoted answers to that stackoverflow question, and it's not clear to me what I should do anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers IE and FF work fine (on Win 7), I was going to be rude about Chrome but I use it the most and can put up with it's doubtful unicode abilities - If you need `monospaced` this can easily be achieved on all SE sites using a pair of `  `backticks.

Comment: @Frank: I don't think I "need" `monospacing` in  the sense of being able to use it in my own posts (though I'm guessing that one will work when I hit *Add Comment*, and I can read yours okay). I'd just like to know why tchrist's posts in particular are inclined to show as  on my displays (I'm seeing 4 squares there, having cut&psted them from his earlier comment).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suspect tchrist is not using a standard windows font for his `monospaced text`. If you open this page in a different browser you can see the difference between my `monospaced text` and his, it's a completely different font and Chrome just isn't that good with fonts. There are a number of font management extensions for Chrome but you'd be better asking on one of the computer related SE sites.

Answer (score 6):

Redundancy is not wrong. Redundancy is merely redundant.

That being said, the statement is not redundant, it is nonsensical. You cannot practice mutually in the first place. You can practice together, though.

Answer (score 1):

*Mutually* is unnecessary here. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutual) has a definition of the base adjective *mutual*:

> directed by each toward the other or the others

But one can't direct the action of practicing toward another, in the same way one can direct, for example, the action of giving a gift. Consider:

I gave a gift to her.
*I practiced a sonata to her.

It is generally only this sort of directed action that can be done mutually.

Comment: how about "we mutually exchanged gifts" vs "we exchanged gifts together" ?

Comment: If my wife and I brought unwanted Christmas presents back to the store in each other's presence, we might be exchanging gifts together. I think.